# Set Authorize in MVC post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorize

I am create a forum website in mvc .it's same functionality like Stack Overflow . Any one  view  other any discussions ,But when anyone put the answer in RichBox,must Login then the answers is created.

So I Used `[Authorize]` in top side of my post action result method

see this

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ViewDiscussion(DiscussionModel discussionModel)
        {
        }
```

Its not working . If any user does not login,Now  when click the post reply(Call Post Method)  button ,It's goes to Login page (because the user did't login), Then the user enter uname and psswrd and signed-in , It's come to the View discussion page .**Now The HttpGet Method is called but i want to Post method call !**

Comment: By default, HTTP uses Get during redirection and so you cannot make a `POST` to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If the ability to update discussion data is a feature only allowed by authorised users, I would add code to the view-model and view to hide the post reply button for unauthorised users.  Or rig it in such a way that an alternative button is rendered, that instead of submitting the form, displays a message informing the user that they need to be logged in to post a reply.

Your alternative, would probably be to hold the form data in `TempData` whilst the user is fed through the log-in process, this would probably be a architecturally messy process though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you can't do what you're asking for, at least not without a lot of dirty hacks.

The reason is simple.  If the user is not authorized, the framework redirects them to the login page to login.  This loses all post information.  Once they login, you cannot magically post the data from the server as a post must come from the client.

The closest you could get would be to somehow track the state they were in, redirect them to a page that recreates the form data as it was and then run some javascript to submit the page.. very messy and hackish, and it easily breaks.

In my opinion, if the user is not logged in, then they should e forced to re-enter their data.  Alternatively, you should design your site so that users can't get at the form page to submit if they are not authenticated.